# How to add items to App menu before File, Edit and View in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, menu, swiftui, menuitem

Using the new SwiftUI `App` model, how can I set the items available on the Menu titled my app name (next to the Apple logo)?

Using the following

```
WindowGroup {
    …
}
.commands { 
    CommandMenu("Menu Name") {
        Button(action: {}) { Text("Menu Item") }
    }
}
```

Will place menus after File, Edit and View. I wish to add an item to the menu titled my app name.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using a `CommandMenu`, use a `CommandGroup` and set its positioning to be one of `.appInfo`, `.appSettings`, `.appTermination`, `.appVisibility`, or `.systemServices`.

For example

```
WindowGroup {
    …
}
.commands { 
    CommandGroup(after: .systemServices) { 
        Button(action: {}) { Text("hi") } 
    }
}
```